# Ajax.BeginForm not posting to controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post my view back to controller using Ajax.BeginForm however it is not working. I have tried several suggestions posted on stackoverflow however none of them work. Below is my code.

//View

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "fundcode", new AjaxOptions() {  HttpMethod = "POST" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FundLocal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-group-addon", @style = "font-weight: bold;" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FundLocal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <label class="text-danger pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FundLocal)</label>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FundEnglish, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-group-addon", @style = "font-weight: bold;" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FundEnglish, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <label class="text-danger pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FundEnglish)</label>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FundCode1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-group-addon", @style = "font-weight: bold;" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FundCode1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <label class="text-danger pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FundCode1)</label>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 pull-right" />
        </div>
    }
```

//Controller Action

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Models.FundCode fundcode)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var db = new Models.FAPEntities();

                if (fundcode.Id == null)
                {
                    fundcode.InsertDate = DateTime.Now;
                    fundcode.InsertedBy = 1;
                    fundcode.UpdatedBy = 0;
                    fundcode.DeletedBy = 0;

                    db.FundCodes.Add(fundcode);
                }
                else
                {
                    var record = db.FundCodes.Find(fundcode.Id);

                    if (record != null)
                    {
                        record.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                        record.FundLocal = fundcode.FundLocal;
                        record.FundEnglish = fundcode.FundEnglish;
                        record.FundCode1 = fundcode.FundCode1;
                        record.UpdatedBy = 1;
                    }
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            ActivateTab(classes.ActiveTab.AddTab);

            ViewBag.FundCodes = new Models.FAPEntities().FundCodes.Where(f => f.DeletedBy == 0).OrderByDescending(f => f.Id).ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

//Model

```
public partial class FundCode
{
    public decimal? Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeleteDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام فند کود را دایر نماید")]
    [DisplayName("نام فند کود (دری)")]
    public string FundLocal { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام فند کود را دایر نماید")]
    [DisplayName("نام فند کود (انګیسی)")]
    public string FundEnglish { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام فند کود را دایر نماید")]
    [DisplayName("فند کود")]
    public string FundCode1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> InsertedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> DeletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: didn't you miss the ajax unobtrusive library in the view?

Comment: we need some more information to solve the problem. Browser Console and your script libraries - JQuery and Ajax-Unobtrusive are required for that matter.

Comment: @MRebati I have already loaded the unobtrusive library and the validation is working fine however the post does not get posted

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "it isn't working" means.  Are there specific errors?  If you open the console network tab do you see the post being made?  Are you able to debug into the controller method?

Comment: @nurdyguy i just found the problem. Actually the jquery unobtrusive is having problem with jquery validate library. If i remove the validation library then it works fine and when i add it again, the same problem occur. But I need both the validation and the unobtrusive library which don't work with each other.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/

Comment: @nurdyguy I have the same version already installed in my project

Comment: @nurdyguy the problem is solved. I had the unobtrusive library and validation library in wrong order